# Python Webscraping: Cannot find elements by xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am quite new to webscraping, but I was attempting to webscrape all the markers seen on https://www2.evphvchargemap.com/map/tokyo in the city of tokyo. I tried to scrape the elements using xpath but it returns an empty array. I was curious if there was also a more efficient way to retrieve such elements. Thank you

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
url = 'https://www2.evphvchargemap.com/map/tokyo'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

# Wait for the page to load (adjust the sleep duration if needed)
time.sleep(30)

# Get the page source
p = element = driver.find_elements("xpath",'//*[@id="map"]/div[1]/section/div/article/div[3]')
# Close the WebDriver
driver.quit()

print(p)
#//*[@id="map_canvas"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/dl/dt
```

I attempted to find using xpath but it returns an empty array. Also, I attempted to load the entire page's html using inspect element but it only displays partially the divisions and could not fully display the spot-name, spot-address  - that is the information I am trying to obtain for all such markets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see on the map is loaded from external URL (luckily in Json format):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

data_url = 'https://www2.evphvchargemap.com/api/Data/chargermap.json'

data = requests.get(data_url).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['dataroot']['ChargerMap'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      SpotId                                           SpotName    SpotLat     SpotLon Type                              ChargerType                                            Addr              Tel                                                                                                                     Open                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Use                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Remarks                                                                                     SpotUrl
0        718                                   トヨタモビリティ東名古屋　新栄店  35.170132  136.923316    1                           200V ケーブル有り 1台                             愛知県名古屋市中区葵１丁目２７番２９号     052-935-6122                                                                                                      8:00～19:00{0}定休日：なし                                                                                                                                                                                                      利用可能カード：EV・PHV充電サポート{0}最大充電時間：1時間                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                詳細は店舗にてご確認ください。                                                                                         NaN
1        858                                    トヨタモビリティ神奈川　武山店  35.222898  139.643923    1                           200V ケーブル有り 1台                                  神奈川県横須賀市武３－７－７     046-857-1441                                                                                                 9:30～18:00{0}定休日：月曜日、火曜日                                                                                                                                                                                                      利用可能カード：EV･PHV充電サポート{0}最大充電時間：1時間                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 詳細は店舗にてご確認ください                                                                  http://www.c-yokohama.com/
2        867                                 トヨタモビリティ東名古屋　鍋屋上野店  35.182980  136.953320    1                           200V ケーブル有り 1台                              愛知県名古屋市千種区谷口町５番３５号    ,052-721-1261                                                                                                      8:00～19:00{0}定休日：なし                                                                                                                                                                                                      利用可能カード：EV・PHV充電サポート{0}最大充電時間：1時間                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                詳細は店舗にてご確認ください。                                                                                         NaN
3        899                                  トヨタモビリティ東名古屋　長久手店  35.171673  137.044353    1                           200V ケーブル有り 1台                                 愛知県長久手市武蔵塚９１０番地  ,0561 - 63 - 88                                                                                                      8:00～19:00{0}定休日：なし                                                                                                                                                                                                      利用可能カード：EV・PHV充電サポート{0}最大充電時間：1時間                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                詳細は店舗にてご確認ください。                                                                                         NaN
4        901                                  トヨタモビリティ東名古屋　山之手店  35.053668  137.149697    1                           200V ケーブル有り 1台                              愛知県豊田市御幸本町一丁目１７６番地  0565 - 29 - 211                                                                                                      8:00～19:00{0}定休日：なし                                                                                                                                                                                                      利用可能カード：EV・PHV充電サポート{0}最大充電時間：1時間                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                詳細は店舗にてご確認ください。                                                                                         NaN
5        967                                 トヨタモビリティ東名古屋　三好ヶ丘店  35.118450  137.111017    1                           200V ケーブル有り 1台                              愛知県みよし市三好丘６丁目４番地の１  ,0561 - 36 - 25                                                                                                      8:00～19:00{0}定休日：なし                                                                                                                                                                                                      利用可能カード：EV・PHV充電サポート{0}最大充電時間：1時間                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                詳細は店舗にてご確認ください。                                                                                         NaN
6       1041                                   トヨタモビリティ東名古屋　荒畑店  35.149990  136.925558    1                           200V ケーブル有り 1台                           愛知県名古屋市昭和区鶴舞４丁目１７番２３号     052-732-3541                                                                                                      8:00～19:00{0}定休日：なし                                                                                                                                                                                                      利用可能カード：EV・PHV充電サポート{0}最大充電時間：1時間                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                詳細は店舗にてご確認ください。                                                                                         NaN
7       1042                                 トヨタモビリティ東名古屋　三好中央店  35.090544  137.069709    1                           200V ケーブル有り 1台                                愛知県みよし市三好町上２３０番地  0561 - 33 - 250                                                                                                      8:00～19:00{0}定休日：なし                                                                                                                                                                                                      利用可能カード：EV・PHV充電サポート{0}最大充電時間：1時間                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                詳細は店舗にてご確認ください。                                                                                         NaN
8       1060                                  トヨタモビリティ東名古屋　島田橋店  35.123910  136.970961    1                           200V ケーブル有り 1台                            愛知県名古屋市天白区元八事３丁目７１番地  052 - 835 - 202                                                                                                      8:00～19:00{0}定休日：なし                                                                                                                                                                                                      利用可能カード：EV・PHV充電サポート{0}最大充電時間：1時間                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                詳細は店舗にてご確認ください。                                                                                         NaN

...
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was curious - how did you find out the data on the map was loaded in from external url - particularly in JSON format?

Comment: @MihirSavkar When you open Web Developer Tools -> Network Tab in your browser and reload the page, you should see this URL with Json data inside...